How to calculate total sum of all the elements present in the list. The elements in the list can be integers or nested lists
def calculate_total_sum(arr):
    # Your code here
    sum=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            sum=sum+arr[i][j]
    print(sum)

list1=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
calculate_total_sum(list1)

getting the error while I am running my code - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

The error message indicates that at least one value in the nested lists is not an integer but rather a string. If this is just because of string-formatted integers you could use something like sum=sum+int(arr[i][j]).

sounds like arr[i][j] is a string, not a number

Typically problems like this use recursive solutions. Recursion isn't particularly performant in Python, but it's still used for illustrative purposes quite often.
Recursive functions need to have at least two paths of execution. The "base case" where we can calculate a straightforward answer, and one or more "recursive cases" where we have to ask the function to keep thinking. Let's try to define those cases before we write the code.

Problem: given a (heterogenous) list of numbers that might be nested arbitrarily deeply, return the total sum of those numbers
Base case: the list is empty, in which case the sum is zero
Recursive case 1: the head of the list is a number, in which case the sum adds that number plus calling this function on the tail
Recursive case 2: the head of the list is a list, in which case the function recurses into both the head of the list and the tail of the list.

Let's implement that, shall we?
from typing import List, Self

type RecursiveNumbers = List[int | Self]

def recursive_sum(numbers: RecursiveNumbers) -> int:
    match numbers:
        case []:
            return 0
        case [head, *tail] if isinstance(head, int):
            return head + recursive_sum(tail)
        case [head, *tail]:  # if not isinstance(head, int) goes unsaid
            return recursive_sum(head) + recursive_sum(tail)

assert recursive_sum([1, [2, 3, 4], 5]) == 15


As I mentioned, recursion isn't particularly performant in Python. A typical Pythonic solution to this sort of problem involves keeping a stack of List[int]s you haven't processed yet and teaching your code to aggregate into it and pull out of it. For instance, consider:
def iterative_sum(all_numbers: RecursiveNumbers) -> int:
    stack = [all_numbers]
    total = 0
    while stack:  # is not empty
        numbers = stack.pop()
        for number in numbers:
            if isinstance(number, list):
                stack.append(number)
            else:
                total += number
    return number


We can use depth first search algorithm here:
Code
def calculate_total_sum(arr):
    def dfs(arr, total):
        if arr is None:
            return total
        if type(arr) == int:
            return total + arr
        for el in arr:
            total = dfs(el, total)
        return total
    total = 0
    return dfs(arr, total)


list1 = [3, 3, [[3, 3, [3, [3, [3, [3, [3, [3, [3, 3, 3]]]]]]], 3]]]
print(calculate_total_sum(list1))

Prints
42
Note

We pass the total sum in the dfs() method.
There are two base cases that we define first in the dfs().
We iterate, and recursively call the dfs() to find all the integers in the array or list.


Side note: isinstace():

Using isinstance() is generally preferred over type() for type checking because it allows for more flexibility and handles inheritance properly.

def calculate_total_sum(arr):
    def dfs(arr, total):
        if arr is None:
            return total
        if isinstance(arr, int):
            return total + arr
        for el in arr:
            total = dfs(el, total)
        return total
    total = 0
    return dfs(arr, total)


list1 = [3, 3, [[3, 3, [3, [3, [3, [3, [3, [3, [3, 3, 3]]]]]]], 3]]]
print(calculate_total_sum(list1))



DFS is a good option. But this code is faster a little bit.
def cumsum(l):
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(e, (float, int)):
            continue

        if isinstance(e, list):
            l[i] = cumsum(e)
            continue

        raise TypeError

    return sum(l)

li1 = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5, [6, [7, [8, [9, [1, [2, [3, 4]]]], 5], 6]], 7]]]
li2 = [3, [3, [3], 3], 3]
li3 = [[[[[3, 3, 3]]]]]

print(cumsum(li1))  # output: 73
print(cumsum(li2))  # output: 15
print(cumsum(li3))  # output: 9

li1 = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5, [6, [7, [8, [9, [1, [2, [3, 4]]]], 5], 6]], 7]]]
li1 = li1 * 1000

%%timeit
cumsum(li1)
# 171 µs ± 6.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

li1 = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5, [6, [7, [8, [9, [1, [2, [3, 4]]]], 5], 6]], 7]]]
li1 = li1 * 1000

%%timeit
calculate_total_sum(li1)
# 2.44 ms ± 18.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


What types of inputs are being accepted? From the fact that you use the default .split() function, I assume that the elements are deliminated by a single whitespace. Is it a string that can look something like this: "1 2 3 [1 2 3 [1 2 [1]]] 4"
If so you can't really use list1=[int(x) for x in input().split()] in order to build a list for this question. This is going to return something like ["1", "2", "3", "[1", "2", "3", "[1", "2", "[1]]]", "4"]
This is probably where your error is stemming from. However, python should be throwing an error when attempting to convert something that isn't convertible to an int into an int so the fact that list1=[int(x) for x in input().split()] is running itself is curious.
Your algorithm itself also has some errors since you're assuming that arr is a simple 2d array of ints (each element of arr is a list where each element of that list is an int), when in reality each element of arr could be an int or a list where each element of that list could also be an int or a list. However, others have already provided good solutions for how to sum a nested list of integers so I would point to their answers if you're looking for an algorithm.

That list comprehension will raise an error if it contains nested lists. It will not return a list of strings

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
